# Problem with FancyBox

Tags: jquery, slideshow, fancybox

I installed a pop-up slideshow gallery using FancyBox /example), which lets you add a caption under the pop-up image, using the title tag.

Unfortunately, when you hover over the thumbnail, the title tag shows up with all the styled code in it, which looks pretty bad.

Is there a way to disable the title hover, without disabling the actual styling itself?

Comment: title of the question should reflect the question itself. yours is meaningless.

Comment: You know how to get your question closed... would you answer a question that has such a title?

Comment: @close voters: Yes, the title is rubbish, but that's easily fixed. What about the actual *question* makes it not "real"? Seems straightforward to me.

Comment: give me the correct code or I shoot!

Comment: @TJ I assume the title has inline markup and is used as alt and displayed in a tooltip which does not support markup. But it's only assumption because the real problem is not really derivable from the 'question'

Comment: For all of the above, please read: [Could we please be a bit nicer to the noobs?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-the-noobs)

Comment: @Redlab: Yes, that's how I read it too. It's not as clear as it should be, but to me, clear enough to keep open and request clarification. Seemed like a lot of knees being jerked by that original title. :-) (Edited version of original comment.)

Answer (score 3):

If there'sa  `title` attribute on the tag, when you hover the mouse over it, browsers supporting the `title` attribute will show it as a tooltip. I'm not aware of any way to modify that behavior.

You could modify FancyBox (and perhaps even offer a patch, supporting the project) to deal with the problem. You can't be the only user running into it. I can think of three ways:

1. Use a different attribute, for instance `data-caption`, for the markup-enabled caption, and use `title` only if that's not there. (Recommending to users that they not put markup in `title`.) (That naming convention, `data-xyz`, is officially approved now in HTML5 for custom attributes.)
2. Remove the `title` attribute after using it to create the caption. (Blech)
3. Pre-process the `title` attribute after using it to create the caption, removing all markup. (Also blech)

I'd go with #1.